# Which events in Event Viewer show which programs accessed my location?

Tags: windows-8, event-viewer, location-services

I receieved a notification in my taskbar that something accessed my location. Right-clicking on the tray icon brings up an option to view location activity in Event Viewer.

[image: Your location has recently been accessed]

However, when I do so the subtree for FileHistory is preselected.

Which events should I be looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up Event Viewer.

- Windows Logs

  - Application

On the right side, you can see the list of access. Some items would have "Location Activity". If you double click on those, you can view details about the application.

[image]